# iPhone - Extending UIWebViewDelegae protocol

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, protocols

I'm using the following code to extend the web view delegate.

```
@protocol CustomWebViewDelegate <UIWebViewDelegate>
@optional
-(void)touchesEnded;
@end
```

In my class I'm implementing web view delegates:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(CustomWebView *)webView
- (BOOL)webView:(CustomWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:
```

My Interface declaration is as following:

```
@interface BrowserView : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, CustomWebViewDelegate>
```

The problem is that its not calling the delegates of web view. why?
Where is my code wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually set your `BrowserView` object as the delegate of a `UIWebView` to get callbacks. You can't just declare yourself as conforming to the protocol and expect to get callbacks. E.g.:

BrowserView.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Then can you show that code please? Also are you sure you're not getting callbacks? Have you put in log lines to confirm?

Comment: Long back i was working on that project and the project was cancelled due to some reasons... i don't have the code with me now.